# Adding a custom field type on K2 component joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-k2, joomla-component

I'm trying to search on google for days already but I couldn't find some useful articles or resources that may able to help me with my concern.

I would like to know if how I would be able to create a plugin for K2 component to add a new field type that would appear on the "Type" drop down field of the "Add Extra Field" form?

Comment: I'm trying it too, if you have found an answer, post it thanks :)

Comment: @tato469 try to checkout the link that I have posted this is the solution I have used I hope it helps you somehow. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have just forgot this post of mine but there is really no way of adding a customized field type in k2 that will appear on the dropdown or something else like but I have used a K2 plugin to add the needed fields that I want here is the link I hope it helps you @tato429 or anyone else having the same concern as I do before http://getk2.org/extend/extensions/date/item/90-example-k2-plugin-for-developers

Comment: Hello, I think I have found more or less the way to add the customize field but is a "hack" way, if I solve it I will post. Thanks for the link, is an usefull tool.

Comment: yup I have saw that part too but I refuse to use it and use to create a plugin to work on it to be safe. good luck in hacking it just let me know how you were able to work on it. ;)